# Matlab: accessing both image sequences from a 3D video file

Tags: matlab, video, 3d, computer-vision, matlab-cvst

I have recorded a 3D video using a Fujifilm Finepix Real 3d w3 camera. The resulting video file is a single AVI, so the frames from both lenses must somehow be incorporated within the single file.

I now wish to read in the video into Matlab such that I have two image sequences, each corresponding to either the left lens or the right lens.

So far I have played back the AVI file using the computer vision toolbox functions (vision.VideoFileReader etc), however it ignores one of the lenses and plays back only a single lens' image sequence.

How do I access both image sequences within Matlab?